# Angular library and peerDependencies resolutions

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, package.json, angular-library, npm-package

I'm trying to develope a library that uses some 3rd party dependency. I followed https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries.

Here is the structure:

```
dist
 |-corp
    |-angular-core
node_modules
projects
 |-corp
    |-angular-core
       | package.json
       | tsconfig.lib.json
angular.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

Here is the library main package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-libraries",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.11.10",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.23",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.801.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^5.1.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tsickle": "^0.35.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
}
```

Here the library projects/corp/angular-core `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "@corp/angular-core",
  "version": "0.3.0",
  "author": "",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": false,
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.23",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.801.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.11.10",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^5.1.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tsickle": "^0.35.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  }
}
```

I built the library and symlinked to the main project through `npm link`, but when I try to run it I got these errors in console:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@next-adv/angular-core/lib/ionic-components/sign-up/sign-up.component.d.ts:5:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx'.
[ng] 5 import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
[ng]                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] node_modules/@next-adv/angular-core/lib/services/authentication/auth.apple.d.ts:3:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ionic/storage'.
[ng] 3 import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
[ng]                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] node_modules/@next-adv/angular-core/lib/services/authentication/auth.facebook.d.ts:3:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx'.
[ng] 3 import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';
[ng]                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] node_modules/@next-adv/angular-core/lib/services/authentication/auth.facebook.d.ts:4:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ionic/storage'.
[ng] 4 import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
[ng]                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] node_modules/@next-adv/angular-core/lib/services/authentication/auth.plain.d.ts:3:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ionic/storage'.
[ng] 3 import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
[ng]                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] node_modules/@next-adv/angular-core/lib/services/authentication/auth.wordpress.d.ts:3:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ionic/storage'.
[ng] 3 import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
[ng]  

                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems like the compiler is looking for the library dependencies in the main project `node_modules`, proof is that only `@ionic` deps, that are not in the main project, gave me errors.

I also tried this in `tsconfig.lib.json` nside the library `angular-core` folder:

```
"paths": {
    "@ionic/storage": [
        "node_modules/@ionic/storage"
    ]
}
```

and in the main project `angular.json`

```
"preserveSymLinks": true
```

but it  didn't work.

I believe that the problem is that the library is installed through a sym-link instead of a regular `npm i`.
So my question is: how do I have to manage the peerDependencies? Do i have to manually install them in the main projects?

Comment: That's what peer dependencies are: dependencies that a library needs and that must be installed in the consuming project.